# Union of a convex domain with closure of a component is open?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a **convex** open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n,\ n\geq 2,$ and let $U$ be a connected component of $(\overline{\Omega})^c.$ Now let $V:=\Omega\cup \overline{U},$ can we prove $V$ is open?

If not, what about the extra assumptions that $\Omega$ is bounded and $U$ is one of the bounded components?

If $\Omega$ is bounded and convex, the conclusion is true. In fact, we know
$\overline{\Omega}$ is bounded and convex, and then $(\overline{\Omega})^c$ is connected. Thus, we have $U=(\overline{\Omega})^c,$ and then
$$\overline{U}=\overline{(\overline{\Omega})^c}=((\overline{\Omega})^\circ)^c=\Omega^c.$$
Therfore, we have $V=\mathbb{R}^n$ is open. **The claim is false, I have made a fatal mistake. $(\overline{\Omega})^\circ\neq \Omega$ in general.**

However, I have no idea for the general case.

**Aschepler have answered the case where $\Omega$ is not connected.**
From which, we can easily get a counterexample where $\Omega$ is bounded connected.

Comment: $\bar U$ denotes the closure in $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Yes, it denotes the closure in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Did you check any examples to verify the truth of the statement that you want to prove?

Comment: @LeeMosher  If $\Omega$ is convex, I have no example to show that $(\overline{\Omega})^c$ admits a bounded component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. As a counterexample, consider in $\mathbb{R}^2$

$$ \Omega = \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |x| < |y| \right\} $$

The complement of the closure is

$$ (\overline{\Omega})^c = \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: |x| > |y| \right\} $$

$\overline{\Omega}$ contains the $x$-axis $(\mathbb{R} \times \{0\})$, and $(\overline{\Omega})^c$ has connected components

$$ \begin{align*}
U_1 &= \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y > |x| \right\} \\
U_2 &= \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y < -|x| \right\}
\end{align*} $$

$(0,0) \in \overline{U}_1$ and $(0,0) \in \overline{U}_2$. Every open neighborhood of $(0,0)$ contains some points in $U_1$ and some points in $U_2$. So no matter which component $U$ is, $(0,0) \in \Omega \cup \overline{U}$ but no open ball containing $(0,0)$ is a subset of $\Omega \cup \overline{U}$, so $\Omega \cup \overline{U}$ is not open.

This example is not difficult to extend to the general $\mathbb{R}^n$, cases where $\Omega$ is bounded, cases where $\Omega^c$ is bounded, and cases where $\Omega \cup \overline{U}$ is bounded.

Comment: Thanks for your patient reply.

Comment: Can you give me an example where $\Omega$ is convex?

Comment: No - intuitively, I think the conjecture is true when $\Omega$ is convex, since it can't have any of these "pinch points". I don't have a solid proof right now either, though.

Comment: I think in this case,  there will exist no bounded components.